# Select required field from line

Tags: awk

```
$ cat file1.txt
test 15 18 17
test1 11 12 14
test2 13 16 19
```

Need to extract only

```
test 12 17 19
```

Preferably using awk one line.

Comment: This is a really hard question to answer. Why 12 17 and 19? What code have you tried to write?

Comment: can you offer rule? or why?

Comment: I just wanted display the selective elements of the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
awk '{a=$1;c=$4;getline;b=$3;getline;d=$4;print a,b,c,d}'
test 12 17 19
```

You does not say how to get the result!!!

```
awk '               # start 
    {
    a=$1            # from first line set a="test"
    c=$4            # from first line set c=17
    getline         # get next line
    b=$3            # from second line set b=12
    getline         # get next line
    d=$4            # from third line set d=19
    print a,b,c,d   # print this
    }' file
```

Comment: Please explain the same as I am a newbie to awk

Comment: Se updated answer.  But you still does not say why you like to get this fields.

Comment: Don't do this. If you don't know why you shouldn't do this, read http://awk.info/?tip/getline repeatedly until you do. If you still don't get it, try to modify that script to, say, print "found" to stderr every time the word "test" is found on a line and then do the same for a script that doesn't use getline - that will highlight just one of the many reasons not to use getline for this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for arrays of arrays (can do similar in any awk with slightly different syntax and a loop):

```
$ awk '{a[NR][1]=""; split($0,a[NR])} END{print a[1][1], a[2][3], a[1][4], a[3][4]}' file
test 12 17 19
```

For comparison with the getline-based solution posted, to modify the above to print "found" to stderr every time the word "test" appears on a line would simply be to add that condition and action once:

```
$ awk '{a[NR][1]=""; split($0,a[NR])} /test/{print "found" |"cat>&2"} END{print a[1][1], a[2][3], a[1][4], a[3][4]}' file
test 12 17 19
found
found
found
```

With the getline solution you'd need to add the test+action repeatedly, once for every line of the input file:

```
$ awk '{a=$1;c=$4;if (/test/)print "found" |"cat>&2";getline;b=$3;if (/test/)print "found" |"cat>&2";getline;d=$4;if (/test/)print "found" |"cat>&2";print a,b,c,d}' file
```

and consider what you'd need to do if your file became 20 lines long instead of 3. This is 100% not an appropriate problem to solve using getline.